# Azure WebSites Standard pricing autoscale

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm a little confused about Azure instance pricing.

Suppose I have one website running on Azure with standard mode. According to the price calculator:

> Load balance unlimited websites per region in up to 10 auto-scaled dedicated instances. Includes support for custom domains and SSL, built-in FTP, Git, TFS and Web Deploy support.

If I choose 1 instance, the price is about $60.

Now if my website needs to use 3 instances, will I pay $60 or $180?

Answer (score 2):

This is out of topic by anyways...If you scale to 3 instances, you'll be using 3 VMs so: hourly rate * number of instances, which in your example would be $180